# Use of variables in postgres script

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, psql

I want to use a variable in my SQL script. Variable's value is 100 (just a number). I have stored it as a csv. file in this directory: C:\Users\Dino\Desktop\my_file.csv.

I want in the sql script to run this:

```
import os
from ask_db import ask_db_params #this script creates the connection to the  database
import sys, os
def my_function(cur, conn):
    sql="""
        \set outputdir'C:\\Users\\Dino\\Desktop'
        \set new_var :outputdir '\\my_file.csv'
         copy my_file to :'new_var';"""

cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    conn = ask_db_params()
    cur  = conn.cursor()
    analysis_data(cur,conn)
    logging.info('Data analysed.')
  except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Failure', exc_info=True)
    exit(1)
```

I have the error:

> syntax error at or near "\" ....

It refers to the first line.

Any help regarding the syntax?

P.S. I m running python to call the sql script. Windows OS

Comment: Do you invoke `psql` to read the script?

Comment: The code is like this: def my_function(cur,conn): sql = """\set outputdir 'C:\\Users\\Dino\\Desktop'
\set new_var :outputdir '\\my_file.csv'
 copy my_file to :'new_var'; """.

Comment: More, more! Please share the whole code. Edit the question to do so.

Comment: I did it. Need more?

Comment: `\set` is a `psql` command. It can't be used outside of `psql`

Comment: thanks for the reply. My question is if it is possible to run a respective command inside the sql script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work. `\set` is a `psql` command, not an SQL command.

You will have to use string manipulation in Python to construct an SQL string that looks like this:

```
COPY my_file TO 'C:\Users\Dino\Desktop\my_file.csv'
```

Then use `execute()` with that SQL string.